# PHP json_encode data to jQuery for AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am having a problem in using `json_encode` function.I am putting a simplified version of the problem here.
Here is the file containing php and jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<?php
$test = "xxxxxxx";
?>

<p onclick="testAjax()">Click here</p> 

<script>
var sendbody;

function testAjax(){
    sendbody = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache:false,
        url: 'testAjaxCall.php',
        data: {sendbody:sendbody},
        success:function(data){
            alert("1");
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("0");
        }
      });
}
 </script>
```

And the ajax file simply contains

```
<?php
    echo "testAjax";
?>
```

When I use `json_encode` function, the jquery code written after using the json_encode function stops working and the ajax function shows neither the success message nor the error message.
However if I write it as

```
sendbody = "<?php echo $test; ?>";
```

In this case the jquery code below this line works and shows success message.

Comment: `the jquery code written after using the json_encode function stops working ...`, where is this `json_encode` function?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve ? Otherwise you don't waiting for json response in your ajax request.

Comment: Look at the message returned by ajax call. You can do it for example via firebug->network->click proper entry and response tab. It will most likely point you towards source of the problem.

Comment: sendbody = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>"; I am not sure you want to enclose a json data within "" but I could be wrong.

Comment: I have written it in this manner for simple representation.Actually I the $test variable contains a whole html file code for which the json_encode function has to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `json_encode`, you don't have to quote the result, it's already quoted.

So change

```
sendbody = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>";
```

to

```
sendbody = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
```

Otherwise you got:

```
 // this cause syntax error
 sendbody = ""xxxxxxx"";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all whenever you are expecting JSON to be returned to your AJAX call you have to tell it that by setting `dataType: 'json',` if not it tries to process it as text and obviously fails (your call is a success but the processing of the response isn't). The next best thing to do is use `console.log(data)` to get a better understanding of the response.